# Making global var from inside a function in PHP

Tags: php, variables, function, global-variables, global

I am trying to define dynamically variables. I am using a function for this, but I don't know how to define the new var as global (because it never created before the function).

is that possible ?

Thanks.

---

### edit

ok, this is what I've built. is it that dangerous ?

```
function extract_values($row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        global $$key;
        $$key = $value;
    }
}
```

and then I'm trying to make my life easier like that:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, address FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        extract_values($row);
#[do some stuff with the variables.]#
}
```

I am doing it to save time. instead of creating for each column it's own variable like

```
$first_name = $row['first_name'];
```

This function does that for me.
I don't see why in this case it might be dangerous..
or as usuall, i am missing something..

Comment: Try to avoid global variables as much as possible!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function doSomething() {
  global $x;
  $x = 5;
}
```

If you prefer to save a couple of bytes, you can use the `$_GLOBALS` array for this:

```
$_GLOBALS['x'] = 5;
```

Comment: Right, but please don't use this in real life. :) One day you'll overwrite variables you didn't intend to this way.

Comment: @deceze, I know. But the OP wants it, so be it. Good practice is secondary to getting the job done sometimes.

Comment: question on that issue: when i use globals - it goes only for the current script right ? i mean, when I change $user_id (as global), on other page, it shouldn't be changed. correct ?

Comment: @OfficeJet Right. Unless you include the other script in the same scope.

Comment: @Jacob thanks. I've just edited the question and added the script. Is that seems to be ok ?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your edit: It makes your code less understandable.

Actually, there already exists a function that is doing this: [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))){
    extract($row);
    // ...
}
```

`extract()` is even better, because it lets you specify what should happen if the variable already exists and/or lets you specify a prefix (so you don't overwrite already existing variables with that name). E.g. you could do:

```
extract($row, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'db');
```

which would result in `$db_first_name` etc.

Surly, `extract()` is also doing some internal work here, but using built-in functions is always better than creating your own.

---

Another possibility would be to use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))){
    list($first_name, $last_name, $address) = $row;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways:

Make the variable global using the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword:

```
function fun1() {
        global $foo;
        $foo = 1;
}
```

Alternatively you can also create an new element in the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array:

```
function fun2() {

        $GLOBALS['bar'] = 1;
}
```

[**Working code**](http://codepad.org/mmWemxgN)

Remember that these are considered bad practice, a function should have local variables invisible outside and should get inputs through the arguments passed. You should avoid getting arguments though global variables and must completely avoid crating global variables.